# In ExpressJS, how should I call an async function from within a post method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This posts to the DB successfully:

```js
var express = require("express");
//rest of boilerplate

//the below function posts 'subscribingUserEmail' argument to the DB
async function postToDB(subscribingUserEmail) {
  await postEmailToDatabase({
    email_address: subscribingUserEmail
  });
}

postToDB("example@gmail.com");

app.post("/emailList", function(req, res) {
  //nothing yet
});
```

This does not:

```js
var express = require("express");
//rest of boilerplate

//the below function posts 'subscribingUserEmail' argument to the DB
async function postToDB(subscribingUserEmail) {
  await postEmailToDatabase({
    email_address: subscribingUserEmail
  });
}

app.post("/emailList", function(req, res) {

  //call the same function but inside the post method instead
  postToDB("example@gmail.com");
});
```

The difference is where I make the async "postToDB" function call. Is there some way to make this function call from within the post method?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just pass `req.body` directly into the `run()` function?

Comment: @Phil the thing is that when I call run("example@gmail.com") above the post method, it works and I can see the email in the DB. But when I call run("example@gmail.com") inside the post method, it does not store the argument email in the DB.

Comment: ^ if i can figure that out, then I can swap the argument for run(req.body.email) inside the post method and should be good. @Peter Jaffray

Comment: What debugging have you done? Some well placed `console.log()` calls should at least inform you what your application is doing. Are you actually sending a `POST /emailList` request to your Express app?

Comment: Everything looks fine. How have you verified that it's _not_ working? How are you making the request to your app?

Comment: I check the DB after the post is executed to verify the working code block, as well as the non-working code block. I can see the post executes in a res.send. As far as console logging, since this is a serverless API the console.log executes on the AWS server and I don't see it in my VSCode terminal. @Phil

Comment: _"I can see the post executes in a res.send"_... what `res.send`? Also, you can [see your Lambda function logs in the Lambda console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-logging.html).

Answer (score -1):

Return the result. This will work assuming postEmailToDatabase is setup correctly in your app

```
async function runSubscribe(subscribingUserEmail) {
  const response = await postEmailToDatabase({email_address: subscribingUserEmail});
return response;
}

app.post("/emailList", async function (req, res) {

  //get the email from the frontend's post request
  subscribingUserEmail = req.body;

  //then pass the email into the top defined function
  const result = await runSubscribe(subscribingUserEmail);

// or const result = await postEmailToDatabase({...})
  
 res.send(result)
});
```

If your req.body has multiple parameters you can deconstruct to keep it clean

`{ subscribingUserEmail } = req.body`

This is assuming you have that parameter on your body object.

If you don't then you'll need to backup and do

`console.log(req.body)`

Comment: Fixed. Thanks Phil.

Comment: The `runSubscribe` is `async`, so it will return a Promise, so that means that `res.send(result)` will be sending an unfulfilled Promise rather than the data

Comment: Doesn't the await catch that?

Comment: The `await` is inside of an `async` function, so it will "extract" the resolved value from the promise returned by `postEmailToDatabase()`, and put that in `response`. However, as you're returning `response` from the async `runSubscribe`, then you'll end up returning a promise that resolves to the `response` value. So you would also need to use `await` in your post callback. If you do that, then `runSubscribe` doesn't need to be async, and could be responsible for just returning a Promise: `return postEmailToDatabase(...)` (it might be worth removing the `runSubscribe` function completely)

Comment: Ah.. I see. So the way I changed it makes more sense right? I put await on the result.

Comment: Yeah, that makes more sense - You can still refactor `runSubscribe`, as it doesn't need to be async anymore (currently you're extracting the value from the promise into `response`, and then wrapping `response` back into a promise), so you can use just `return postEmailToDatabase({email_address: subscribingUserEmail});` from the `runSubscribe` function (but if you do that, then runSubscribe is simply just calling a function and returning that value, it might be worth removing runSubcribe all together)

Comment: I'm relatively new.  Thank you for teaching me Nick :)